# How to display repeater field in a select field using Advanced Custom Field?

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I can't find a way to connect the repeater field to the select field. I just need some assistance and suggestions on how to do it.

Comment: Do you just want a repeatable select field or what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: What i am trying to do like using select field to display a specific repeater field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I think this is what you are asking, is a conditional logic for all fields in ACF so you can set up repeaters to show like the screenshot below.

[image]